# Swapping Value Program throws error

Tags: java

Just to be clear, **I have done** my research on the error that I'm getting, `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10`.  I have been looking on SO for a while and none of the solutions provided work.  What is partially confusing me is the line where the error is being thrown.  **This is not a duplicate thread from the threads with the **

I am writing a program that swaps the value of two indexes of an array (part of a greater sort program).  I am getting the error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10`.  There error is pointing to the line in my code `if(data[i] > data[i+1]){`.  I can't figure out what is causing the error, but I know it is probably something very simple that I am missing.

```
public static int length = 10;
public static int[] data = new int[length];
data[0] = 1;
data[1] = 10;
data[2] = 5;
data[3] = 11;
data[4] = 9;
data[5] = 2;
data[6] = 7;
data[7] = 9;
data[8] = 8;
data[9] = 10;
public static void exchange(){
    int temp = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
        if(data[i] > data[i+1]){
            temp = data[i+1];
            data[i+1] = data[i];
            data[i] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated:)  Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you say `i+1` on the **next** line, use something like

```
for(int i=0;i<length - 1;i++){
    if(data[i] > data[i+1]){
```

**Alternatively**, you could use something like

```
for(int i=1;i<length;i++){
    if(data[i-1] > data[i]){
        temp = data[i];
        data[i] = data[i-1];
        data[i-1] = temp;
    }
```

Comment: lol - I knew it was something that simple.  Thanks for answering.  +1

Answer (score 3):

By doing `i+1`, you are trying to access an index of the array that does not exist when `i` equals `length - 1` (9). You can't access the variable you are trying to the way you are doing it.

Answer (score 2):

On the final iteration of the `for` loop, `i` equals 9. Your `if` statement then tries to compare `data[9]` to `data[10]`, which results in an exception because the highest index in `data` is 9.

Comment: Yeah, this. Posted it same time I did. :)